# How to add next and prev button in wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

I have created a wordpress post. Used page break to break the page. Page numbers are working. But how can i add prev and next button insted of page number pagination??

Comment: Do you use paginate_links()?

Comment: </div>
    <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
     
    </div>
i used this one

Comment: You May Refer https://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this following code

```
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'before'           => '<p>' . __( 'Pages:' ),
        'after'            => '</p>',
        'link_before'      => '',
        'link_after'       => '',
        'next_or_number'   => 'next', //change into number for numeric pagination
        'separator'        => ' ',
        'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next page' ),
        'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page' ),
        'pagelink'         => '%',
        'echo'             => 1
    );

        wp_link_pages( $args );

?>
```

reference : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages

hope it helps